# ng-click for an entire DIV in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Whenever any element inside my DIV is clicked I want to execute a function in Angular controller.

How to do this?

Basically I am looking to place a ng-click on DIV element and expect the ng-click event be called when any/all elements nested inside the div are clicked.

How to achieve this requirement?

Comment: Place the `ng-click` on this div? Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes. I did. It doesn't seems to fire/called.

Comment: A container with `ng-click` and a button inside that container with `ng-click` can demonstrate it. When you click the button inside the container, the ng-ckick of button will be triggered first there after the click of container will also be triggered

Answer (score 1):

Here both the container and the button has click events. When you click the button, the click event of its parent will also be triggered. This is called Event Bubbling in JavaScript

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.clicked = function() {
        console.log("Clicked Me");
    };
    $scope.secondclick = function() {
        console.log("Button Clicked")
    }
});
```

```css
.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    background: cyan;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div class="container" ng-click="clicked()">
        <button ng-click="secondclick()">Click Me</button>
    </div>
</div>
```